# How to get response data from Facebook Request Dialog using URL redirect?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the full URL redirect to display my app request dialog, where users can invite their friends to play the game. As it described in [Facebook Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) documentation, I use the following URL:

```
    https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?
       app_id=APP_ID&
       message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&
       redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

But how do I get the response data after invitation request is clicked? As it is also described there, that it will return the Request ID and the recipient user IDs.

Answer (score 0):

When using the URL version of the dialog, you get parameters passed to the end of your `redirect_uri`, something like

`http://www.example.com/response?request={request_id}&to[0]={fb_uid}&to[1]={fb_uid}&…`